# Is there a way to generate a type within a template class out of a template argument and a string

Tags: c++, templates, generics

i want to improve my code by getting rid of some template arguments. I have an idea but struggling with the correct code. Its also possible that c++ does not have such an feature, which would be also fine.

The current code looks like this:

```cpp
class ModelProperties{
public:
    string name;
};

class Model{
public:
    ModelProperties properties;
};

template <class TModel, class TModelProperties>
class ModelWrapper{
private:
    TModel m_model;
public:
ModelWrapper(TModel model){
    m_model = model;
}

TModelProperties getProperties(){
    return m_model.properties;
}
};
```

I would like to have something like this:

```cpp
template <class TModel>
class ModelWrapper{

private:
    TModel m_model;

public:
ModelWrapper(TModel model){
    m_model = model;
}

TModel + "Properties" getProperties(){
    return m_model.properties;
}

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This question boils down to deducing the return type of `ModelWrapper::getProperties`. Given that you really want to return a copy and not a reference, there are these equivalent options:

```
auto getProperties() const { return m_model.properties; }

std::remove_reference_t<decltype(TModel::properties)> getProperties() const
{ return m_model.properties; }
```

---

If you do not want to use the `auto` keyword in a signature (perhaps for the sake of documentation), rather declare a type alias for the properties for each `Model`:

```
class Model {
public:
    using properties_t = ModelProperties;
    properties_t properties;
};
```

which you can substitute for `auto` like so:

```
typename TModel::properties_t getProperties() const { return m_model.properties; }
```

---

Alternatively, if your `Model` classes were defined as templates like so:

```
template <typename TProperties>
class Model {
public:
    TProperties properties;
};
```

you could do:

```
template <template <typename TProperties> class TModel>
class ModelWrapper {
    ...
    TProperties getProperties() const { return m_model.properties; }
};
```

where `TProperties` is automatically deduced during the instantiation of `ModelWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use `auto`/`decltype(auto)` or `decltype`:

```
template <class TModel>
class ModelWrapper{
private:
    TModel m_model;
public:
    ModelWrapper(TModel model) : m_model{model} {}

    auto getProperties() const { return m_model.properties; } // Return by copy (unless properties **is** a reference)
};
```

or

```
decltype(auto) getProperties() const { return (m_model.properties); } // Extra parenthesis for reference.
```

or

```
auto getProperties() const
-> decltype(m_model.properties)& // By reference
{ return m_model.properties; }
```